# Why using static volatile for variables and only static for arrays in TWI library?

Tags: i2c, c, array, variables

I want to know why to declare variables with static volatile and arrays with only static in TWI library?

For example;

```
static uint8_t twi_masterBuffer[TWI_BUFFER_LENGTH];
static volatile uint8_t twi_masterBufferIndex;
static volatile uint8_t twi_masterBufferLength;
```

Comment: Do you understand what `volatile` does?

Comment: I learned something like that this variable maybe changed but in which aspect I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

You use `volatile` to mark variables that are going to change at any moment, in a ISR (Interrupt Service Routine) typically.

You mark them so the compiler doesn't optimize, and always go and pick its actual value. If you don't do that, then an ISR may update a variable while the main "thread" of execution keeps using its old value. That's is a nasty situation to debug.

You only need to mark variables that are used both in the ISR and in the main sketch. If `twi_masterBuffer` is not changed inside an ISR, you don't need to mark it with `volatile`.

`static` is used inside function to mark variables that need to be permanent, i.e., keep their values between calls, but not accessible from outside that function.

Comment: I'm studying the TWI library, to modify my I2C library because my I2C library has a bug, and I went back to learn about the well professional written code for I2C which is the TWI library. So, I'm going through C techniques of coding. And, now this is going more difficult to me because after looking over and over to the code, I looked to the ISR and it has operations of sending and receiving data, then what's going in the actual functions?

Comment: static and volatile are a different aspect of programming, but very related, because I have to understand what actual functions do and what ISR also do, and then I may understand what static and volatile means.

Comment: static variables are declared at the head of the .c code, they are not inside any function, so how would they be used from outside the function? Or, the static goal here is to keep the values of these variables constant between all the functions inside TWI library, right?

Comment: @PerchEagle. You are confusing `static` with `const`.

Comment: No, I know const means this value is not changed what so ever, but static means the value must not changed to reset between the calls of single or different functions.

Comment: @PerchEagle. Static global variable means: this variable is global to all functions in the file (.ino) where it's declared, and unknow in other files (.ino). Non-static global variable means they are global across all files in the project. It's not about the value; it's about where it's allocated (heap vs stack), what is his lifetime (forever vs only during that particular function call), and where it's know (one file vs all files in the project). C/C++ is tricky, tricky.

Comment: Yes, so there are advs and disadvs between static and non-static. Static holds its value between all functions but the non-static is not. Non-static is recognized in all files where static is not. But there's no type of variables which can hold the value and also be recognized within other files? Is that possible?

Comment: OK, so `twi_masterBuffer` is not modified, its role is like a storage for TX or RX operations, and copied from the user data in or out.